# Which Sabre API can get count of booked passengers on a flight?

Tags: api, sabre

I need help to identify an API that can give us a count of passengers booked on a flight. Input is greatly appreciated. Thnx.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a community around programming, coding. Please show us a [mre].

Comment: Which Sabre API do you consider, SOAP or REST?

Comment: Hi Christina, we would prefer SOAP but we can use REST as well.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are sabre web services that can provide that information, but which service you use depends if you're within the flight operational window or not.  If the flight is initialized and within the operational window (which is normally 3 - 5 days before flight departure) you can use the ACS (airport control system) services.

- ACS_FlightDetailsRQ - This will return a count of passengers booked in each cabin of a flight
- ACS_PassengerListRQ - This will return more detailed information for all passengers that are booked on a flight.

If you're before the operational window, then you need to use other services that show the booked passengers on the flight.  From memory I think TripReportsRQ is a web service that can provide that information.

Also there's always the SabreCommandLLSRQ service that will let you issue native sabre commands to obtain this information.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, there's no API that can give you such information (unless you're the airline, of course).

I believe that the information that you'd need would be the available seats, for you which you can use the service *[Air Availability.](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/search/Air_Availability)* This will show you the available spaces up to 9, but it depends on the airline how much you see. Even if you see 4, it could still mean that there are more available for that RBD (class of service).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to glean some of that information from pulling up a seat map API ([perhaps Get Seat Map Counts?](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/search/get_seat_map_counts)), but the number of assigned seats likely does not match the number of ticketed passengers for a given flight.

You'd have to use back office data or some sort of queue spectra kind of process to find the number of passengers booked from your own agency on a given flight, there is no API that I know of that would do that for you.

Comment: Not all tickets have a seat assigned, so, as you said, it likely won't match that.